# Why wasn't this contract deployed fully?

Tags: solidity

Here is this (example) contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xCD74B4f10E883761D2672c37b3aF3591F7fe353e#code

As you can see in 'Read Contract' and 'Write Contract' tabs, only methods available are these:

- isFinalizeAgent
- isSane
- crowdsale
- distributedReservedTokensDestinationsLen
- reservedTokensAreDistributed
- token
- finalizeCrowdsale
- distributeReservedTokens

But if you check contract's source, you will see 1,634 code lines, and it contains much more methods and members.

So, my questions are:

1. Why wasn't this contract fully deployed? (the majority of functions aren't present in Etherscan)
2. What command arguments to `solc` did the developer use to only compile part of the contract?
3. Is it possible to detect what methods/members are going to be compiled as the end result, only by looking at the source of the contract?
4. I am correct in my assumption that only part of contract was compiled or, was it compiled fully, but it is just the ABI that was reduced and this is why Etherscan isn't showing all the functions?
5. I also see that SafeMath functions are linked against an external contract,  how do you tell the `solc` compiler that all the calls to Safe Math have to be made through an external contract?

Answer (score 2):

The contract that was deployed is `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent`. If you look, it is declared, with *inheritance*, as such:

```
contract ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent is FinalizeAgent
```

So Etherscan will give you access only to the functions declared in `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` and `FinalizeAgent`. What are those functions? Exactly the subset you mentioned.

The other contracts are *composed* instances:

```
contract ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent is FinalizeAgent {
  using SafeMathLibExt for uint;
  CrowdsaleTokenExt public token; // <-- Here
  CrowdsaleExt public crowdsale; // <-- And here
```

So it is the `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` instance that will call `CrowdsaleTokenExt` and `CrowdsaleExt` methods. Not you from Etherscan.

1. -4 In Ethereum, all transactions are atomic. There is no such thing as "partially" deployed.
2. `SafeMathLibExt` has to be [`--link`ed](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=--link) into the `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` bytecode at or after compilation. Truffle's deployer can also [do it for you](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations) with `deployer.link(SafeMathLibExt, ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent);`.

Comment: but there is also this line: `contract CrowdsaleTokenExt is ReleasableToken, MintableTokenExt, UpgradeableToken` . Why wasn't it also deployed, if it is of similar syntax? Why only `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent`, and not also `CrowdsaleTokenExt`?

Comment: I understand the transactions are atomic, but still don't understand why was this contract compiled partially.

Comment: here `contract Haltable is Ownable` is also declared with inheritance but it is also out of the resulting bytecode

Comment: A composed contract can have its own inheritance. But because `CrowdsaleTokenExt` is composed, its inherited functions will not show in `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent`. This is OOP 101.

Comment: If you have an `Apple is Fruit` in a `Bag`, the functions of `Apple` and `Fruit` will not be accessible from the `Bag`.

Comment: I understand that there are classes and there are instances of these classes. But where in that code, it says that only `Apple` , and not `Peach` was instantiated?

Comment: On the Etherscan link you posted, look for "Contract Name: ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent"

Comment: The only appearance of it is on line 1556 : `contract ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent is FinalizeAgent ` , as you said it yourself it is only a DEFINITION of the class. DEFINITION is not a DECLARATION, therefore , no instance of the class will be created. But where is the DECLARATION (i.e. the instantiation) of the class ? How does Etherscan knows that the only object from this bunch of declared classes was only `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` ??

Comment: You only looked at the long source code. Take your eyes away from the long source code, to the fields above it. Do you see the green tick with " Contract Source Code Verified (Exact Match)"? Well, `Contract Name: ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` is right there, 30 pixels below it.

Comment: When you submit code to Etherscan, you give it the long source code, and you tell it which of those contracts to verify. It then proceeds to verify the one you told it to verify. Try it yourself on Ropsten.

Comment: let say Etherscan ceases to exist, and all you have is the source code of the contract and the Main Net. How do you know then, that the deployed binary corresponds to `ReservedTokensFinalizeAgent` and not any other contract, declared in this source file?

Comment: You would compile the source code with all known compiler versions, and you would check whether any of those compiled codes perfectly matches the `data` in the transaction that deployed that contract. Give or take the constructor arguments and the swarm hash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Etherscan's Read/Write utilities reflect the actual deployed code. You could always test the missing functions you suspect in Remix.

1. Copy the source from Etherscan, paste it into Remix as a new source file
2. Go to the "Run" tab, enter the contract address in Remix's "At Address" input
3. Expand the Deployed Contracts section and you'll see all functions that you can interact with directly from Remix using MetaMask.

In our platform, we see mismatches in contract transactions and what Etherscan says are verified source/ABIs. Some stuff just doesn't decode indicating that the deployed contract does not match what Etherscan thinks is at that address.